# How to create a page in a prestashop module such that the output is not wrapped in the site's template html AND using translation?

Tags: module, controller, prestashop

**What I know to do:**

1) Create a module controller that allows translation.

I can declare texts to translate either in the controller itself or in the template:

> /modules/mymodule/controllers/front/list.php

```
class myModuleListModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->l('Some text to translater');
        $this->setTemplate('list.tpl');
    }
}
```

> /modules/mymodule/views/templates/front/list.tpl

```
{l s='Some other text' mod='mymodule'}
```

2) I know to create some output that is not embedded in html, like for instance some json object:

> /modules/mymodule/json.php

```
include( '../../config/config.inc.php' ); 
echo json_encode(array('key' => 'Some text'));
```

**What I need:**

I need to be able to translate some text AND have the output sent to the browser without the surrounding html. I have to be able to do one of those:

- use a standalone file and be able to declare text to translate, similar to this (does not work):

  ```
  include( '../../config/config.inc.php' ); 
  echo json_encode(array('key' => l('Some text')));
  ```
- use a module controller and force raw output, similar to this (does not work either):

  ```
  class myModuleListModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
  {
      public function initContent()
      {
          parent::initContent();
          $this->noHtml = true;
          echo json_encode(array('key' => l('Some text')));
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Do you want to get a some HTML from your FrontController via Ajax?

Comment: @gskema It is similar to that. If you give an answer for getting a html bribe via Ajax, it will most likely answer my question. I'm in a very special case though : I want to proxy a download link to check if the user is logged and has permission, and then either display a localized error message, send the file, or redirect to login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to translate text in FrontController, you can only do it in two ways:

Translate the texts inside a template

```
// Inside module front controller

$template = '.../template.tpl'
$this->context->smarty->fetch($template)

// Inside template.tpl

{l s='Translateable text' mod='mymodule'}
```

Or use strings already translated inside main module file

```
 // Inside module front controller
 $this->module->l('My string');

 // But it has to already exist inside mymodule.php
 $this->l('My string'); // You don't have to use it, it just has to exist to get scanned by RegEx.
```

If you want to return something back to Ajax request in your module front controller

```
 public function init() {

 parent::init(); // If you need to

 // Some code here

 if (Tools::getValue('ajax'))
 {
     header('Content-Type: text/html');
     die($this->context->smarty->fetch($template));

     // Or
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     die(Tools::jsonEncode($response_array));
 }
```

There is also a function called

```
FrontControllerCore::getLayout @ Line 1209
```

Which you can use to override the whole page template, however, it should be used to create unique display for products and other page (like full screen product presentation, etc.)

If you want to ouput a file yourself while not providing a full file path to the user:

```
 public function init() {

    parent::init(); // If you need to

    if (ob_get_level() && ob_get_length() > 0)
        ob_end_clean();

    // Set download headers
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    // Prevents max execution timeout, when reading large files
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    while (!feof($fp))
        echo fgets($fp, 16384);

   exit;
```

Apart from that, I don't image what else would tou possibly need to build your app. Always send token to your controllers for security!

Comment: Thank you alot. This provides more details than what I expected, and also helpful background information.